# How to await API results in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

I have React-Typescript app with with backend calls using React Saga. When one of my functions from frontend executes a backend call, before its execution next function from frontend starts executing.

I have used SETTIMEOUT function and it works ! Just wanted to know if there's any other way around.

Frontend Code :

```
{ this.props.ValidateClient(validatorObject) }
this.finalvalid(clientIn)
```

React Saga Code :

```
export function* ValidateClient(action) {
    try {
        console.log("1");
        yield put(validateClientRequest());
        console.log("2");
        const data = yield call(() => {
            return  axios.get('https://localhost:44325/api/Clients/' + action.payload.firstName + "/" + action.payload.lastName + "/" + action.payload.Email);
        }
        );
        console.log(data);
        console.log("3");
        yield put(validateClientSuccess(data.status));
        console.log("4");
      
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(validateClientfailure(error));
    }
```

After logging 1,2 in console the second function starts executing !

How can serially execute React Saga code and then move to second function ?

Comment: After leaving my answer I looked back at the question and saw that you are calling `this.props.ValidateClient()`.  You aren't calling the saga directly, are you?  If it's correct then `this.props.ValidateClient` should just `dispatch` some action that gets picked up in the saga by a `take` and passed off to the `ValidateClient` saga.

Comment: Yes doing exactly like that. Dispatching an action for running saga to pick and pass on

Answer (score 0):

Your inline arrow function is **not** async.  You are just returning the `Promise` and not `await`ing it.  I'm not sure if this is definitely a problem (as `aync` functions inherently return a `Promise` too), but I suspect that it will work better if you externalize the async logic into a separate function and `call` it.

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

interface Payload {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  Email: string; // is this really uppercase?
}

type YourResponseType = any; // fill this in

const callApi = async ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  Email
}: Payload): Promise<AxiosResponse<YourResponseType>> => {
  return await axios.get<YourResponseType>(
    "https://localhost:44325/api/Clients/" +
      firstName +
      "/" +
      lastName +
      "/" +
      Email // don't you need to URL encode this??
  );
};

export function* ValidateClient(action: { payload: Payload }) {
  try {
    console.log("1");
    yield put(validateClientRequest());
    console.log("2");
    const data = yield call(callApi, action.payload);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("3");
    yield put(validateClientSuccess(data.status));
    console.log("4");
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(validateClientfailure(error));
  }
}
```

Try this.  I can't guarantee that it's correct since your example is not fully reproducible.

Comment: It's still working the same. After logging 1, 2 it is moving on to next function.

Comment: @utkarsh If you are able to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on CodeSandbox etc perhaps I can be of more help.